# How to write Riemann sums to find definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I'm doing a question where I need to prove that a function, $x^2 + 2x$ is Riemann integrable on the interval $[-3,3]$.

The question also gives me the interval $2n$, first $n$ intervals in $[-3,-1]$ with the width of $2/n$ and second $n$ intervals in $[-1,3]$ with the width of $4/n$.

I have already been given the suggested workings but I cannot seem to understand.

The workings given to me for lower Riemann are as follows:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n f\left(-1-\frac{2i}{n}\right)\frac{2}{n}
+ \sum_{i=1}^n f\left(-1-\frac{4i}{n}\right)\frac{4}{n}
$$

Which ends at $18-\frac{36}{n}+\frac{12}{n^2}$ which equals to 18 when $n$ approaches infinity.

I can understand the intervals $\frac{2}{n}$ and $\frac{4}{n}$. But I cannot understand the brackets with $(-1-\frac{2i}{n})$ and $(-1-\frac{4i}{n})$.
Why is $-1$ the start and not $-3$?

Comment: I guess $f$ is the name of the function $x\mapsto x^2+2x$, The bracke are added probably to disambiguate the formulæ. It starts with $-1$ and ends with $-3$ – this doesn't change the sum.

Comment: Your sums are not correct

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah yea that's what I thought that's why I'm doubting the model answers. Yet it ends at the right answer that's why I'm so confused.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

If the function $ f $ is Riemann integrable at $ [a,b] $ then

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(a+i\frac{b-a}{n})=\int_a^bf(x)dx$$

With $ (a,b)=(-3,-1) $, the sum becomes
$$\frac 2n\sum_{i=1}^nf(-3+i\frac 2n)$$

and with $ (a,b)=(-1,3) $, it gives
$$\frac 4n\sum_{i=1}^nf(-1+i\frac 4n)$$

Comment: Is this applicable to lower riemann sum?

Comment: @jeff What do you call "lower" Riemann sum.